# Return custom user type from QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qmodelindex

I have a `QAbstractItemModel` that wraps some custom data (a vector of pointers). I use this model with a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, `QTreeView` and such.

When connecting some other logic to the `selectionChange` signal, I need the user data. Not some view of it, the pointer itself.

I've added a special case to the data method.
`QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override`

When I pass in -1 as a `role`, I return a pointer to my user type in the variant. It is quite hacky, there has to be a better "official" way to do this.

How does one return the underlying model data from a `QModelIndex` and such?
Thank you.

Comment: provide a [mcve], please

Comment: When reacting to `selectionChanged` in your widget, you should know that you are dealing with your own subclass of `QAbstractItemModel`, so why don't you define a separate method in your model ( e.g. `getItemsVector`) that returns the data structure you are seeking? No need to use `data()` for this

Comment: Doesn't `QModelIndex::data()` return the underlying model data for that index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current way is in fact quite close to what Qt proposes to use: you are passing -1 as a role to tell the model to return your custom data while Qt encourages you to use another value for the role: [Qt::ItemDataRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) enumeration ends with `Qt::UserRole` item equal to `0x0100`. As the documentation says, it is the first role that can be used for application-specific purposes. So instead of passing -1 to the model you could pass `Qt::UserRole`. Should you ever need to use some other kind of application-specific data, use `Qt::UserRole + 1` as a role. For others you can use `Qt::UserRole + N`.

There's, however, another way: as one of the comments points out, if you definitely know which model is used in the view, you can simply cast `QAbstractItemModel` to your particular model and use some model-specific API to extract the data you need:

```
void MyView::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselect)
{
    MyModel * myModel = qobject_cast<MyModel*>(model());
    if (!myModel) {
        // Whoops, something went wrong, not the right model!
        <...> // process it somehow
        return;
    }

    <...> // Use myModel to retrieve the required data using convenient model-specific API
}
```

If you need to get the model from `QModelIndex`, just use `qobject_cast` as shown above on `QModelIndex::model()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only hacky thing about it is that you are passing an integer explicitly. I use models that return pointers to the actual object all the time, simply by dedicating a particular `dataObject` role, or however you chose to name it.